# React DateTimePicker

Tags: reactjs, datetimepicker, react-datepicker

Using React DateTimePicker I am trying to Update the new date on change, but its not getting updated with the new Date. can anyone tell me what is wrong over here?

```
  import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';

 const [values, setValues] = useState(new Date()); 

const onDateTimeChangeHandler = (newDate) => {
    setValues(newDate);
  };

<DateTimePicker
  onChange={onDateTimeChangeHandler}
  value={values}
 />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the return statement. So nothing was returned from the render. You need to add the return statement when rendering a react page.

```
const App = () => {
const [values, setValues] = useState(new Date()); 

const onDateTimeChangeHandler = (newDate) => {
   setValues(newDate);
};

return (
<DateTimePicker
   onChange={onDateTimeChangeHandler}
   value={values}
/>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
 
export default function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(new Date());
 
  return (
    <div>
      <DateTimePicker
        onChange={setValues}
        value={values}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```